# Remove comma's between the [] brackets in string using c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want remove comma's between the square brackets[] instead of entire comma from the string.

Here my string is,

```
string result= "a,b,c,[c,d,e],f,g,[h,i,j]";
```

Expected output:

```
a,b,c,[cde],f,g,[hij]
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: What you need is a simple state machine... It can be in two states: inside brackets or outside brackets... from there it is simple.

Comment: @Corak Why not just post that as an answer?

Comment: Do you have to handle nested brackets?

Comment: @Corak In that case why post it at all if you're not sure it's correct.  BTW it is.

Answer (score 4):

As I've written, you need a simple state machine (inside brackets, outside brackets)... Then for each character, you analyze it and if necessary you change the state of the state machine and decide if you need to output it or not.

```
public static string RemoveCommas(string str) 
{
    int bracketLevel = 0;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);

    foreach (char ch in str) 
    {
        switch (ch) {
            case '[':
                bracketLevel++;
                sb.Append(ch);
                break;

            case ']':
                if (bracketLevel > 0) {
                    bracketLevel--;
                }

                sb.Append(ch);
                break;

            case ',':
                if (bracketLevel == 0) {
                    sb.Append(ch);
                }

                break;

            default:
                sb.Append(ch);
                break;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Use it like:

```
string result = "a,b,c,[c,d,e],f,g,[h,i,j]";
Console.WriteLine(RemoveCommas(result));
```

Note that to "save" the state of the state machine I'm using an `int`, so that it works with recursive brackets, like `a,b,[c,d,[e,f]g,h]i,j`

Just as an interesting exercise, it can be done with a slower LINQ expression:

```
string result2 = result.Aggregate(new 
{
    BracketLevel = 0,
    Result = string.Empty,
}, (state, ch) => new {
    BracketLevel = ch == '[' ? 
        state.BracketLevel + 1 : 
            ch == ']' && state.BracketLevel > 0 ? 
                state.BracketLevel - 1 : 
                state.BracketLevel,
    Result = ch != ',' || state.BracketLevel == 0 ? state.Result + ch : state.Result
}).Result;
```

In the end the code is very similar... There is a state that is brought along (the `BracketLevel`) plus the string (`Result`) that is being built. **please don't use it**, it is only written as an amusing piece of LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Regex approach

```
string stringValue = "a,b,c,[c,d,e],f,g,[h,i,j]";
var result = Regex.Replace(stringValue, @",(?![^\]]*(?:\[|$))", string.Empty);
```

if you don't have nested brackets

Comment: Thanks for this.  It took a while to find a regex that actually worked.  I had to adjust for angle brackets in my case: `@",(?![^>]*(?:<|$))"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var output = new string(result
                         .Where((s, index) => s != ',' ||
                                              IsOutside(result.Substring(0, index)))
                         .ToArray()
                       );

//output: a,b,c,[cde],f,g,[hij]
```

And

```
private static bool IsOutside(string value)
{
     return value.Count(i => i == '[') <= value.Count(i => i == ']');
}
```

> But remember this is not the efficient way of doing this job.